# Share event bus btw client app and server actors

Tags: architecture, client-server, communication, actor, vert.x

*What are pros/cons to push events directly from client to server-side verticles through [Event Bus Bridge](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs_event_bus_bridge)? In other words what are the benefits of sharing event bus between client app and server actors?*

---

As you know [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/docs/) is an event-loop that urge you to use smth like actors model. Separate actors (verticles) could communicate among each other with help of [EventBus](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus).

### Common Approach

AFAIK, common approach to arrange client-server communication is to use the next scheme:

1. Expose web service (router) which will accept requests from client
2. Web sevice send event to verticle/actor.
3. Verticle/actor makes computations and return results
4. Web service get computation results and send them back to client

### Vert.x Event Bus Bridge approach

What tangles me is that client side Javascript could communicate directly with each actor/verticle at server-side:

1. Client initialize Event Bus in browser
   `const eb = new EventBus('http://localhost:8080/eventbus')`
2. Client send event directly to specific server-side actor 
   `eb.send('some-address', {name: 'tim', age: 587});`
3. Client receive answer from specific server-side actor 
   `eb.registerHandler('some-address', (error, message) => { ... })`

### Questions

1. What are the benefits of using direct client-actors communication instead a traditional one?
2. What about security? Now each verticle should be secure?
3. What about code simplicity? From one side things become a little bit easier, but you haven't got single entry point of any more. Is this new approach acceptable for not trivial applications with complex back-end?
4. Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it depends – as always. Asynchronous and non-blocking communication is more [resilient than synchronous communication](https://thenewstack.io/synchronous-rest-turns-microservices-back-monoliths). Caller isn't blocked and communication is loosely coupled. With the Event Bus you could also benefit from pub/sub communication (and other messaging patterns). There is a good book about Reactive Messaging Patterns with the Actor Model from V. Vernon available.

Regarding security, you would only [allow some queues to be available for clients](https://vertx.io/blog/vert-x3-real-time-web-apps/). Vert.x calls these [inbound and outbound addresses](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_securing_the_bridge). Than you don't need to "secure" each Verticle because the client can't reach them directly.

If you have "real-time" use case, in the sense that clients need to be notified as soon as possible without to press reload, than I would go with the Event Bus communication (e.g. chat, etc.). But who says you could only do one thing? You could just notify for important changes (without the data) via the Event Bus and let the client retrieve the changed data via a plain & simple web service endpoint.

For more insights on the Actor Model I recommend reading [Concurrency Programming for Scalable Web Architectures](https://berb.github.io/diploma-thesis/original/042_serverarch.html) or the book Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks.

**Edit Plain WebSocket vs. Event Bus Bridge:**

Vert.x Web comes with an [Event Bus Bridge based on SockJS](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs). It integrates Web clients with the Vert.x Event Bus. SockJS even enables WebSocket-like communication in older browser over techniques like long polling:

> Under the hood SockJS tries to use native WebSockets first. If that
> fails it can use a variety of browser-specific transport protocols and
> presents them through WebSocket-like abstractions.

Vert.x states that as:

> WebSocket-like interface which just works.

So, basically the Vert.x Event Bus Bridge uses WebSocket if it's available in the clients browser. Hence, I would prefer the Event Bus Bridge over an own WebSocket implementation.

Comment: thanks for excellent answer and book suggestions!! Could you please share your considerations about why websockets and event bus bridge aren't mutually exclusive? When you should use websockets and when event bus? Websockets also allow you to notify client ASAP. In other hand event bus may do all the same things as websockets, right? So which part of communication you'll suggest to keep at websockets adn which move to event bus?

Comment: Edited my answer. I suggest to use plain HTTP calls for all non-notify stuff and for the "real-time" stuff use the Event Bus Bridge.

Comment: Similar frameworks like SockJS are [Socket.IO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) and [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-javascript).

Comment: More precise: I didn't meant WebSockets and the Bridge aren't mutually exclusive. I meant that plain HTTP calls and the Bridge/WebSockets aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: could you please explain why you prefer plain HTTP for all not-notify stuff?

Comment: I wouldn't say I prefer it, but I like REST APIs because they are simple to use even in Terminal with Tools like `cURL`. As I said it depends on the use-case. Event-like stuff over request/response isn't going to work very well, therefore you would need messaging WebSockets or the Event Bus. With messaging you could go with the push principle and with request/response you would go with pull principle.

Comment: But you could notify over messaging. If the client really wants to get the new data, just send an plain old HTTP request to an REST endpoint and get the data. This way would be preferable in case of few events with a lot of data. If you have many events with few data include the data in the events.